# How to set my flag variable 0 everytime my page gets refreshed in DialogFlow?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to **set my flag variable 0 everytime a new user comes to my website or an existing user refreshes the webpage**. Where should I declare this flag variable in my code?
This is my index.js :

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin=require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
console.log(`1`);
var flag=0; 

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
console.log(`2`);
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log(`3`);

  function welcome(agent) {
    console.log(`4`);
    var query=request.body.queryResult.queryText;
    query=query.toLowerCase();
    console.log(query);
    console.log(flag);
    agent.add(`Welcome user`);
  }


  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

I am not able to figure this out as firebase console shows no logs when I refresh my page i.e., **I want a function similar to 'onload' in DialogFlow fulfillment**.

Comment: This looks like the fulfillment code. It would be helpful if you updated your question to include screen shots of the Intents from the Dialogflow console and give some indication how you are calling Dialogflow *from* your web page.

Comment: I've only 1 intent in my console. I am using SalesIQ bot integrated with DialogFlow. My welcome message comes from SalesIQ which gives the user 2 suggestions-Export or Import. I have put 'Export' and 'Import' as 'training phrases' in DialogFlow Console. Then my flow jumps to fulfillment code and I have 2 parameters in Welcome intent-phone and mail. I want to ask about these parameters one by one in fulfillment code. I am able to do this but my flag does not reset to 0 even if I reload my page. So is there any 'onload' kind of function in DialogFlow fulfillment? Do you still want screenshots?

Comment: Yes. Screenshots will help. Any information at all will help. You mention SalesIQ bot, I assume this is the one from Zoho? Is there anything about that integration you can provide? The more you tell us about what you're doing, the better our chances are of helping you.